# Difference between FileIO object and object returned by open(filename, mode)

Tags: python-3.x, file-io, io, isinstance, bytesio

Python has several io base classes including

```
IOBase
RawIOBase
BufferedIOBase
TextIOBase
```

as well as several derived io classes:

```
FileIO
BytesIO
```

Now, when i create a `BytesIO` object, the mro is:

```
[<class '_io.BytesIO'>, <class '_io._BufferedIOBase'>, <class '_io._IOBase'>, <class 'object'>]
```

and when i create a `FileIO` object, the mro is:

```
[<class '_io.FileIO'>, <class '_io._RawIOBase'>, <class '_io._IOBase'>, <class 'object'>]
```

This is pretty straightforward.

However, when i open a binary **file** for writing using the built-in open, i get the mro:

```
[<class '_io.BufferedWriter'>, <class '_io._BufferedIOBase'>, <class '_io._IOBase'>, <class 'object'>]
```

Isn't a command which opens a **file** expected to return a `FileIO` object according to the principle of least surprise?
I just wrote a method which accepts either a `BytesIO` or a **file** and i stumbled over my `if isinstance(io.FileIO) ...` clause.
What is the difference between a `FileIO` object and the object returned by open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference is that `FileIO` inherits from the `RawIOBase` class which provides low-level access to the OS-level API, but the `open` function return a `BufferedIOBase` inheritor, which is more suitable in generic case (I think)). As the side effect `FileIO` can work with the OS-level file descriptors as a name (`open` allows the path-like only). So the `FileIO` provides more flexible API to work with binary files or streams (for example to reduse the memory usage, etc), `open` - doesn't. More info about the difference [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase).

Figuratively speaking - `open` is a swiss knife for the files genrally, `FileIO` is a surgeon's scalpel.

So for your problem, may be the `isinstance` is not right choise, may be it's better to use "duck-typing" approach and check that the object has the necessary methods (or use another type to check with `isinstance`, for example `IOBase` if it covers your needs). Also you can use `readable()`, `seekable()`, `writable()` methods of the object to check the necesasary conditions

Comment: Thank you for your answer, esp pointing out the readable()... etc. methods. To the background: I have written a class with a `from_file(f: io.IOBase)` method. If it's given a file it determines the file size and load the content into an internal buffer. If it's given a BytesIO it uses getbuffer to get the contents and size and then proceeds like in the other case. According to your duck typing suggestion i would need to check for existance of `f.getbuffer()` or `f.name`. Another possibility would be to check for `BytesIO` and assume it's a `FileIO` else.